# need to sort in order

Tags: linux, grep

I need below output to get an order.

```
var="vas-1 vas-2 vas-3 .... vas-10 vas-11"
echo $var | egrep 'vas-[0-9]'
```

Output:

```
vas-1
vas-10
vas-11
vas-2
vas-3
..
```

Expected output

```
vas-1
vas-2
vas-3
..
vas-10
vas-11
```

Comment: A bit surprising output, as with your commands, I get `vas-1 vas-2 vas-3 .... vas-10 vas-11` in one line.

Answer (score 2):

Coreutils `sort` should do the job

```bsh
$ var="vas-1 vas-2 vas-3 .... vas-10 vas-11"
$ echo "${var// /\\n}"
vas-1
vas-10
vas-11
vas-2
vas-3
..

# Sorted
$ echo "${var// /\\n}" | sort -n -t '-' -k 2
vas-1
vas-2
vas-3
..
vas-10
vas-11
```

The `${var// /\\n}` is `bash` specific thing. It replaces spaces with newlines, so it will print newline-separated output.

Comment: The -n option is for nymeric sort and -k and -t selects the "key field" from the input.

Answer (score 0):

With the `zsh` shell:

```
# use an array instead of a scalar variable to store several values:
$ array=(vas-10 vas-2 vas-3 .... vas-1 vas-11)
$ print -rC1 -- ${(no)array}
....
vas-1
vas-2
vas-3
vas-10
vas-11
```

Where the `o` [*parameter expansion flag*](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags) `o`rders the elements of the array upon expansion and `n` makes that order `n`umeric (and `print -rC1` prints them `r`aw on `1` `C`olumn).

If the data has to be originally in a scalar variable and you want to split it on space, you can do:

```
array=(${(s: :)var}) # split explicitly on SPC only
```

or

```
array=($=var) # split on $IFS (SPC, TAB, NL, NUL by default)
```